# Geometrical question about solid angles

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

In the study of thermal radiation, emission is usually described in terms of solid angles.
My question is: why is $dA_{jp} = cos(\theta_j ) dA_j$ in the below figure? How can I understand this geometrically? I tried deriving this relation by starting with the fact that $dA_{jp} = rd\theta * rsin(\theta)*d\phi$ then got stuck after that. Any help is greatly appreciated!

(The image below is from page 11 of Radiative Heat Transfer by Michael Modest.)

[image]

Comment: $dA_{jp}$ appears to just be the standard differential surface patch on a sphere of radius $r$.  The *real* question (by which I mean the one that seems most physically relevant to your problem), is what is $dA_j$? If you can answer that question, then I think we're done.  Can you tell us what $dA_j$ represents?  It's got to be in the surrounding text somewhere. And perhaps what $p$ is supposed to reference.

Comment: The text states that $dA_{jp}$ is the projection of the area $dA_j$ onto the unit hemisphere. So I think $dA_j$ is some arbitrary surface area.

Comment: It might be the surface where thermal radiation ends up. (Or a surface element of that surface, to be precise...)

Comment: Ancillary question. Is it possible to tile the surface of the sphere with identical tiles? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

$dA_{jp}$ is the projection of the vector $\mathbf{\hat n_j}dA_j$ onto the unit normal vector at $p$ on the unit sphere. So, you take the dot product:
$$dA_{jp}=\mathbf{\hat n_p}\cdot \mathbf{\hat n_j}dA_j=\cos(\theta_j)dA_j.$$
Note that in the diagram, the author labels the vector $\mathbf{\hat n_j}$ but does not label the vector that it is projected onto. I used the label $\mathbf{\hat n_p}$ for the unlabeled vector for the sake of clarity.